# Nashorn can't load js files with multi-line comments?

Tags: javascript, java-8, nashorn

I'm not sure this is WAD but I get "Expected an operand but found *" when a script file under Java 8 uses the load() function where the loaded JS file contains multi-line comments.

/*
Doesn't work
*/

// Does work

I can't find any mention of a limitation here https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions.

Single line comments work though....

Comment: Could be but multi-line is supported in JavaScript and scripts not used by the load() function work fine.

Comment: How about providing a small example capable of reproducing the problem?

Comment: load("/common/somescript.js");

Comment: That’s not allowing us to reproduce the problem. Neither do we have the file `/common/somescript.js` nor the code surrounding that single `load` invocation.

Comment: I agree with Holger, you need to post the problematic code. I tried a simple example and didn't have any errors.

Comment: For some reason it stopped happening. I'll update if I find a reproducible way to see it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Removing the comments from the left makes it eval fine.  https://gist.github.com/silasb/f05dc6acf3e7958da618387c45860906